# How to change the type of a parent class' property in a child class?

Tags: java

I have a parent class as follows:

```java
public class ParentClass {
  protected List<String> property = null;
  public ParentClass() {
    this.property = new LinkedList<String>();
  }
    //property gets populated here
  public boolean parentClassFunc(String where){
    assert property != null;
    for(String it : property) 
        { 
            if(where.equals(it))return true; 
        }
        return false ;
  }
}
```

And I want to speed up this Class by extending it and making some changes, one change includes changing the type of `property` from `LinkedList` to `HashSet` to take advantage of O(1) `.contains` on that type.

This is what the `ChildClass` would look like:

```java
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

  //make property a HashSet instead of LinkedList

  @Override
  public boolean parentClassFunc(String where){
    assert property != null;
    return property.contains(where);
  }
}
```

How can I change the property type in a `ChildClass` in Java?

Comment: Seeing as the field isn't final, you can just assign it again in the child class constructor. That's not "changing the type" though. You'd just be overwriting the previously initialized value with another one.

Comment: @Michael then if I use that property in the overridden function will it use the property defined in the child class constructor instead of the parent class?

Comment: You'd want to specify the field as a `Collection<String>`, since those are the only common interfaces. Unfortunately you lose the advantage of a `Set` or `List` reference. Rather than have the parent class declare the field, you could simply leave it up to the base class and then each class can use `List` or `Set` accordingly.

Comment: "How to change the type of a parent class' property in a child class?" You can't.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a constructor overload for the child to specify its own collection type:

```
public class ParentClass {
  protected Collection<String> property = null;

  public ParentClass() {
    this(new LinkedList<>());
  }

  protected ParentClass(Collection<String> property) {
    this.property = property;
  }
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  public ChildClass() {
    super(new HashSet<>());
  }
}
```